# SDL_AddTimer + SDL_GL_MakeCurrent not working on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I'm messing around with C++, OpenGL and SDL doing a game that should be able to run in Windows and Mac OS X.
I have a problem that only happens on Windows.

Let me describe the scenario.

First I create an OpenGL renderer and get the current context:

```
this->renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(this->window, rendererIndex, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
this->context = SDL_GL_GetCurrentContext();
```

[Complete code here](https://github.com/felipowsky/GrifoEngine/blob/0b8e6c8771309e1b9c494b2ddeaafeb0fdc11c69/sources/Window.cpp#L103-L130)

In my scene I add a timer to create some asteroids:

```
this->timer.Start(INTERVAL_CREATE_ASTEROID, SpaceshipScene::CreateAsteroidTimer, this);
```

Internally this timer uses SDL_AddTimer and keeps the current window and context for itself:

```
this->window = SDL_GL_GetCurrentWindow();
this->context = SDL_GL_GetCurrentContext();
this->callback = callback;
this->param = param;
this->timerId = SDL_AddTimer(interval, Timer::ExecuteCallback, this);
```

When the callback executes I use MakeCurrent to make sure that OpenGL will run in the right context (the window and context from the main thread):

```
bool hasContext = timer->window != NULL && timer->context != NULL;

if (hasContext) {
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(timer->window, timer->context);
}

Uint32 result = timer->callback(interval, timer->param);

if (hasContext) {
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(timer->window, NULL);
}
```

[Complete code here](https://github.com/felipowsky/GrifoEngine/blob/5c050ee35bf6c8ab897eed77e78e38f66e237aa7/sources/Timer.cpp#L19-L33)

On Mac OS X this code is working perfectly, but on Windows it isn't drawing the asteroids on the window neither throwing any error.

What am I doing wrong?